# Why is running time of the same algorithm different in doubling ratio test?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I am analyzing brute force Three Sum algorithm. Let's say the running time of this algorithm is **T(N)=*a*N^3**. What I am doing is that I am running this ***ThreeSum.java*** program with *8Kints.txt* and using that running time to calculate constant ***a***. After calculating ***a*** I am guessing what the running time of *16Kints.txt* is. Here is my ***ThreeSum.java*** file:

```
    public class ThreeSum {
        public static int count(int[] a) {
            // Count triples that sum to 0.
            int N = a.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                        if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                            cnt++;
            return cnt;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            In in = new In(args[0]);
            int[] a = in.readAllInts();
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            int count = count(a);
            StdOut.println("elapsed time = " + timer.elapsedTime());
            StdOut.println(count);
        }
    }
```

When I run like this:

```
$ java ThreeSum 8Kints.txt
```

I get this:

```
elapsed time = 165.335
```

And now in doubling ratio experiment where I use the same method inside another client and run this client with multiple files as arguments and wanna try to compare the running time of ***8Kints.txt*** with above  method but I get different result actually faster result. Here is my ***DoublingRatio.java*** client:

```
public class DoublingRatio {
    public static double timeTrial(int[] a) {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        int cnt = ThreeSum.count(a);
        return timer.elapsedTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in;
        int[][] inputs = new int[args.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            in = new In(args[i]);
            inputs[i] = in.readAllInts();
        }

        double prev = timeTrial(inputs[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            double time = timeTrial(inputs[i]);
            StdOut.printf("%6d %7.3f ", inputs[i].length, time);
            StdOut.printf("%5.1f\n", time / prev);
            prev = time;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this like:

```
$ java DoublingRatio 1Kints.txt 2Kints.txt 4Kints.txt 8Kints.txt 16Kints.txt 32Kints.txt
```

I get faster reuslt and I wonder why:

```
 N      sec   ratio
2000   2.631   7.8
4000   4.467   1.7
8000  34.626   7.8
```

I know it is something that has to do with Java not the algorithm? Does java optimizes some things under the hood.

Comment: Wonder if JIT time is involved. What happens if you do the first `timeTrial` twice? Change your loop to start at 0 rather than at 1. You should get a ratio of 1.0 for N = 1000.

Comment: it might be becuase crossin of CPU CACHE but more likely first run involves initing stuf on JAVA JRE which is not done in the other runs ... its common problem in benchmarking ... you need to invalidate chaches and init what you can before measuring